# nodemon starting `node server.js` TypeError: marked is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jsdom, dompurify

I'm creating a blog, using this 'Web Dev Simplified' tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NrHkjlWVhM

I've copied the code from git hub https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Markdown-Blog, installed the node modules and linked it to my mongodb database online.

Node Modules include;
express, mongoose, ejs, --save-dev nodemon, slugify, method-override, dompurify, jsdom.

The database was working and I could save articles, until I added the last part about sanitizing HTML and converting markdown to HTML, this is when the 'TypeError: marked is not a function' comes up, and the save button ceases to work.

Seems a once understood function is now not understood because of a more recent node module dependency, either the dompurify library or jsdom. I'm really out of my depth here! please help!

Comment: Ok so I have managed to get it to work, or rather a friend of mine did. The line in question was here, on the models/articles.js file:                                   if (this.markdown) {
        this.sanitizedHtml = dompurify.sanitize(marked.parse(this.markdown))
  }                                                                       
 .parse needed to be added. Dont ask me how it works, but it does, I'm not even sure what parse means yet! So many thanks to Carl!

Answer (score 1):

From Marked Documentation:
https://marked.js.org/#demo

```
Node JS
import { marked } from 'marked';
// or const { marked } = require('marked');
const html = marked.parse('# Marked in Node.js\n\nRendered by **marked**.');
```

Your Code:

```
if (this.markdown) {
   this.sanitizedHtml = dompurify.sanitize(marked(this.markdown))
}
```

try this:

```
if (this.markdown) {
   this.sanitizedHtml = dompurify.sanitize(marked.parse(this.markdown))
}
```

its work for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
const { marked } = require('marked');
```

instead of

```
const marked = require('marked')
```

...

```
this.sanitizedHTML = dompurify.sanitize(marked.parse(this.markdown))
```

Per node example documentation at https://marked.js.org/#demo